# Updating NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uilabel, swift5

Hello I am now doing a project where I have to support rtl text in my labels

I had this snippet which is written in swift 3 but it not longer work for swift 4 and 5. I tried updating it but I cloud not figure how to update it

```
extension UILabel {
func decideTextDirection () {
    let tagScheme = [NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage]
    let tagger    = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: tagScheme, options: 0)
    tagger.string = self.text
    let lang      = tagger.tag(at: 0, scheme: NSLinguisticTagSchemeLanguage,
                                      tokenRange: nil, sentenceRange: nil)

    if lang?.range(of:"ar") != nil {
        self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
    } else {
        self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    }
}
```

to use this add following with your label :

```
detailLabel.text = details[0]

detailLabel.decideTextDirection()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw your extension in a Playground and hammered out the compiler errors. Here's what I came up with:

```
extension UILabel {
    func decideTextDirection () {
        let tagScheme = [NSLinguisticTagScheme.language]
        let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: tagScheme, options: 0)
        tagger.string = self.text
        let lang = tagger.tag(at: 0, scheme: NSLinguisticTagScheme.language,
                                   tokenRange: nil, sentenceRange: nil)

        if let _ = lang?.rawValue.contains("ar") {
            self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
        } else {
            self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        }
    }
}
```